# the best way to animate canvas with low cpu use?

Tags: canvas, jquery-animate, cpu

What is the best way to animate canvas with low cpu use?
For now I use setInterval(Something,100);

Answer (score 0):

checkout `requestAnimationFrame`

http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/